# Mixing ASP.NET pages with ASP Pages in windows server 2003 IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I've got a lot of Classic ASP pages in production on a Windows Server 2003 64-bit machine. I've also got .NET on there working.

I'm starting to move the ASP ajax pages (pages that receive ajax calls from the Classic ASP) to ASP.NET/C# to take advantage of the business/data/logging layer I've got set up there in C#.

I've figured on securing the ASPX pages by way of a "token" that I create in the database in ASP and then pass to the ASPX page, which then uses it to validate that it's a legit call and destroys it.

My big question is - aside from making the ASPX pages, do I need to compile the app into the same site as the ASP site? I assumed I'd do that - deploy it there alongside the ASP Classic pages, and then just call the ASPX individually as needed.

Is this strategy sound? Do I need to do anything special for performance or configuration to make ASP Classic and ASP.NET coexist well?

Thanks - this migration has been a bear because of the extreme asp classic dependency.

Answer (score 1):

It will work just fine. I've seen it on several sites. Just put them all in the same directory.

Your biggest issue will be that the ASP and ASP.NET pages will each have their own SESSION and APPLICATION variables which won't be shared between the two. If you are using session variables in either it can force you into doing a lot of hacks to make it all work together well.

Comment: I'm not sharing session - I'm generating tokens from the ASP pages (guids from the db) and then passing those to the asp.net pages to verify "session". At this point I'm just using the ASPX pages as calculators and savers and updaters.